# Flutte Firebase Database query

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

this is my flutter database Structure ..

```
final notesReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
await notesReference.child("data").orderByChild("displayDescription").equalTo('23').once().then(
```

Result is nothing list is empty.. why?

without equalTo('23') working fine .. i also try to change my rule

```
{
"rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true,    
     "data" : {
         ".indexOn": ["displayDescription"]
     }

    }
}
```

just want where displayDescription = "23" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think child of 'displayDescription' is not a string. But, you are querying a string '23'. Try parse string or remove '' sign

Comment: sorry its string only i wrongly created for demo i update now